# use has attribute selector on specific element

Tags: jquery

I'm trying to use the ["has attribute selector"](https://api.jquery.com/has-attribute-selector/) on a specific div with an ID. I tried the below code but that doesn't seem to work.

```js
var divElement = $("#" + divID);

$('[data-role=selectbox]', divElement).each(function () {
  $(this).getKendoSelectBox().enable(enable);
});
```

Comment: How exactly does it not work?  Your example seems incomplete.  Where is `enable` defined?

Comment: Post the HTML you're using this with. We need a [mcve]

Comment: @JasonP - no, that's using [selector context](https://api.jquery.com/jquery/#selector-context) which is similar to `.find()`

Comment: So who is supposed to have the "data-role" attribute? The "divID" div? Or some of it's internal children nodes?